# How to get the MySQL query cache hitrate?

Tags: mysql, query-cache

All these sites online are telling me to maximise this number, but how do I actually retrieve it from MySQL? I'd like to use it to figure out the total number of queries that have been run, too, working that out mathematically off hits vs the hitrate.

Is there any way to retrieve the total number of queries run, or the hitrate of the query cache, from MySQL?

Comment: try `show engine innodb status`

Comment: I can read the total queries in the big long string output by that command, and the hit rate looks to be about 40%, but is there any way to fetch this data for display in a web based admin interface?

Comment: this may also help you if you want to use it for that purpose: http://www.dbtuna.com/article/46/query_cache_size_%7C_the_performance_impact_of_the_MySQL_Query_Cache